# Why the SQL script can run in the local environment but can not run in the other server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I write a SQL script to map the name to report name. I have verify in my local SQL server 2012 machine. it works well. however, when I run in the sever, I got error

> Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 40
>   Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

and I also tried to run the "select" part directly in the remote server and result is correct too.
I don't understand why it is error. have any idea? (notes: I add "error here-->" in the error line)

```
DECLARE @jobTable TABLE 
(
  job_name nvarchar(max),
  report_name nvarchar(max),
  event_type nvarchar(max),
  description nvarchar(max),
  last_run_date int,
  last_run_time int
)

declare
  @job_name uniqueidentifier,
  @report_name nvarchar(max),
  @event_type nvarchar(max),
  @description nvarchar(max),
  @last_run_date int,
  @last_run_time int,
  @last_run_dur int



/************** alert ********/
declare getId_alertjob_cursor cursor for (
     SELECT 
       [jobs].[name] job_name,
       alertFeed.relativePath report_name,
         CONVERT(nvarchar(max), SUBSTRING([steps].[command], CHARINDEX(' @EventType=''', [steps].[command], 0) + LEN(' @EventType='''), CHARINDEX('''', [steps].[command], CHARINDEX(' @EventType=''', [steps].[command]) + LEN(' @EventType=''')) - CHARINDEX(' @EventType=''', [steps].[command], 0) - LEN(' @EventType=''')), 0) event_type,
       [steps].[last_run_date] last_date,
       [steps].[last_run_time] last_time,
       [steps].[last_run_duration] last_dur
       FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs] [jobs] INNER JOIN [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobsteps] [steps] ON [jobs].[job_id] = [steps].[job_id], ReportingService_4c0ed75e1e8c4e50acbf853867f071f3_Alerting.dbo.AlertDefinition [alertDef], ReportingService_4c0ed75e1e8c4e50acbf853867f071f3_Alerting.dbo.Feed [alertFeed]
       WITH (NOLOCK)
       WHERE [jobs].[name] <> 'syspolicy_purge_history' 
       and alertDef.scheduleid = CONVERT(nvarchar(max), SUBSTRING([steps].[command], CHARINDEX(' @EventData=''', [steps].[command], 0) + LEN(' @EventData='''), CHARINDEX('''', [steps].[command], CHARINDEX(' @EventData=''', [steps].[command]) + LEN(' @EventData=''')) - CHARINDEX(' @EventData=''', [steps].[command], 0) - LEN(' @EventData=''')), 0)
       and alertDef.FeedId = alertFeed.FeedId
);

open getId_alertjob_cursor 
error here-->    fetch next from getId_alertjob_cursor INTO   @job_name,   @report_name,  @event_type,  @last_run_date,  @last_run_time, @last_run_dur

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
--     INSERT INTO @jobTable VALUES (@job_name, @report_name, @event_type,'Alert',0,0);
--   ,@last_run_date,@last_run_time);
     fetch next from getId_alertjob_cursor INTO   @job_name,   @report_name,  @event_type,  @last_run_date,  @last_run_time,@last_run_dur
END

close getId_alertjob_cursor
deallocate getId_alertjob_cursor
```

Comment: yes, both of them are MS SQL server 2012

Comment: are you passing the same set of parameters?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it is because there are jobs with steps that don't contain the phrase `@EventType='` and this is causing your substring to fail.

Add a quick check in to make sure it exists first, something like this:

```
Case 
        When CHARINDEX(' @EventType=''', [steps].[command]) > 0 Then
        CONVERT(nvarchar(max), SUBSTRING([steps].[command], CHARINDEX(' @EventType=''', [steps].[command], 0) + LEN(' @EventType='''), CHARINDEX('''', [steps].[command], CHARINDEX(' @EventType=''', [steps].[command]) + LEN(' @EventType=''')) - CHARINDEX(' @EventType=''', [steps].[command], 0) - LEN(' @EventType=''')), 0) 
        Else ''
        End as [EventType]
```

Just noticed you have this in your WHERE clause:

```
and alertDef.scheduleid = CONVERT(nvarchar(max), SUBSTRING([steps].[command], CHARINDEX(' @EventData=''', [steps].[command], 0) + LEN(' @EventData='''), CHARINDEX('''', [steps].[command], CHARINDEX(' @EventData=''', [steps].[command]) + LEN(' @EventData=''')) - CHARINDEX(' @EventData=''', [steps].[command], 0) - LEN(' @EventData=''')), 0)
```

You should also add a check to see if the `command` field contains `@EventData`

Maybe if you try to explain what you are trying to acheive someone may post a better query.

Comment: hummm....it does not make sense to me, becasue it works well if I just run the

select xxxxx (the same code in the getId_alertjob_cursor)

in the remote server

Comment: I would like to try to map the SQL agent job name to the report name. the first step it to parse the command of the agent job. the comment is look like 

{
`code`[ReportingService_4c0ed75e1e8c4e50acbf853867f071f3_Alerting].dbo.AddEvent @EventType='FireSchedule', @EventData='32BA4917-EC6A-40EC-86A9-7323CF0DD6DF'
`code`
then I can get the eventType and EventData

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to mention that there is no need to use a cursor in this case. I.e. your query can be simplified to the following:

```
DECLARE @jobTable TABLE 
(
      job_name SYSNAME
    , report_name SYSNAME
    , event_type NVARCHAR(1000)
    , [description] NVARCHAR(2000)
    , last_run_date INT
    , last_run_time INT
)

INSERT INTO @jobTable 
(
      job_name
    , report_name
    , event_type
    , last_run_date
    , last_run_time
)
SELECT 
      d.job_name
    , report_name = alertFeed.relativePath
    , d.event_type
    , d.last_date
    , d.last_time
FROM (
    SELECT 
          job_name = j.[name] 
        , event_type = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' @EventType=''', s.[command]) > 0 
            THEN CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), SUBSTRING(s.[command], CHARINDEX(' @EventType=''', s.[command], 0) + LEN(' @EventType='''), CHARINDEX('''', s.[command], CHARINDEX(' @EventType=''', s.[command]) + LEN(' @EventType=''')) - CHARINDEX(' @EventType=''', s.[command], 0) - LEN(' @EventType=''')), 0) 
            ELSE ''
          END
        , last_date = s.[last_run_date] 
        , last_time = s.[last_run_time] 
    FROM [msdb].dbo.sysjobs j WITH (NOLOCK)
    JOIN [msdb].dbo.sysjobsteps s WITH (NOLOCK) ON j.job_id = s.job_id 
    WHERE j.[name] != 'syspolicy_purge_history' 
) d
JOIN [ReportingService_4c0ed75e1e8c4e50acbf853867f071f3_Alerting].dbo.AlertDefinition [alertDef] ON alertDef.scheduleid = event_type
JOIN [ReportingService_4c0ed75e1e8c4e50acbf853867f071f3_Alerting].dbo.Feed [alertFeed] ON alertDef.FeedId = alertFeed.FeedId
```

Also, I'm disconcerted by the database [ReportingService_..._Alerting]. If it's located on the same server where the task is  being executed, probably, it is worth to refuse to use the database.